# Mounting FTP as filesystem in debian using curlftpfs

Tags: debian, filesystems, ftp, openvz

I am trying to mount a FTP as filesystem in debian using curlftpfs. What I get after running

`curlftpfs -o allow_other username:password@ftp.server.com /mnt/myftp/`

is just:

`fuse: failed to open /dev/fuse: Permission denied`

even when run as root. What am I doing wrong? (curlftpfs is in version `curlftpfs 0.9.2 libcurl/7.21.0 fuse/2.8`)

edit:

When I write `ls -lah /dev/fuse`, I see

`crw-rw---- 1 root fuse 10, 229 Apr  9 00:34 /dev/fuse`

...but even when I add both myself and user `root` to group `fuse`, neither me (as a user) or user `root` can mount ftp, I still see

`fuse: failed to open /dev/fuse: Permission denied`

edit2:
Even if I write this fairly insecure and crazy line:

`sudo chmod a+rwx /dev/fuse`

I still get the permission denied message. Which permissions could be denied?

edit3:

I forgot to mention I am on VPS with OpenVZ. I thought that there is no issue with this, but apparently, there is! I am adding the resolution as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is an issue in OpenVZ. One can't mount FUSE systems (curlftpfs uses fuse) from inside an OpenVZ system.

There is a how-to for OpenVZ here : http://wiki.openvz.org/FUSE , but one needs an access to the outside machine. I don't have that.

Answer (score 0):

Use sudo command it worked for me.

```
$sudo curlftpfs -o allow_other username:password@ftp.server.com /mnt/myftp/
```